# How to stop svg animation with css?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to stop animation when my animation is completed. I am made one box and box made a "S" symbol. When my box make S then I want to stop my animation in S place.

```
<svg  viewBox="0 -150 300 600" width='400px' height='100%' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' onload='Init(evt)'  enable-background="new 0 0 141.4 141.4">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var SVGDocument = null;
        var SVGRoot = null;
        function Init(evt) {
            SVGDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
            SVGRoot = SVGDocument.documentElement;
        }
        function Pause() {
            SVGRoot.pauseAnimations();
        }
        function Play() {
            SVGRoot.unpauseAnimations();
        }
    </script>
    <g id="Layer_1_copy">
        <animateTransform begin="Layer_1.mouseover" id="delayone" dur="6980ms" onend='Pause()' type="translate" attributeType="XML" attributeName="transform" />
        <animateTransform begin="Layer_1.mouseover" id="delaytwo" dur="6990ms" onend='Play()' type="translate" attributeType="XML" attributeName="transform" repeatCount="indefinite" />

        <path fill="#5DB228" stroke="#FFFFFF" d="M70.7,70.7L35.3,35.3L70.7,0L106,35.3L70.7,70.7z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="45 210 -11" dur="7000ms" begin="Layer_1.mouseover" end="Layer_1.mouseout"/>
        </path>

        <path fill="#5DB228" stroke="#FFFFFF" d="M70.7,0L0,70.7V0L70.7,0L70.7,0z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="-45 -60 -30" dur="7000ms" begin="Layer_1.mouseover" end="Layer_1.mouseout" />
        </path>

        <path fill="#5DB228" stroke="#FFFFFF" d="M141.4,141.4L70.7,70.7L141.4,0V141.4z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="-45 10 141" dur="7000ms" begin="Layer_1.mouseover" end="Layer_1.mouseout"/>
        </path>

        <path fill="#5DB228" stroke="#FFFFFF" d="M141.4,141.4L70.7,70.7L0,141.4H141.4z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="45 114 97" dur="7000ms" begin="Layer_1.mouseover" end="Layer_1.mouseout"/>
        </path>

        <path fill="#5DB228" stroke="#FFFFFF" d="M141.4,0H70.7L106,35.3L141.4,0z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="45 -57 28" dur="7000ms" begin="Layer_1.mouseover" end="Layer_1.mouseout" />
        </path>

        <path fill="#5DB228" stroke="#FFFFFF" d="M35.3,106V35.3L0,70.7v70.7L35.3,106z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="45 -67 173" dur="7000ms" begin="Layer_1.mouseover" end="Layer_1.mouseout"/>
        </path>

        <path fill="#5DB228" stroke="#FFFFFF" d="M70.7,70.7L35.3,35.3V106L70.7,70.7z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="-135 53 123" dur="7000ms" begin="Layer_1.mouseover" end="Layer_1.mouseout"/>
        </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

When box make S then I want to stop animation in S place.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is using `fill="freeze"` for each animation. This makes the graphic stay in place where the animation ends. The default fill method is to reset it back to it's starting point.

Comment: Thank you Joachim for your response.. I find-out solution.

Comment: Now i have some error like this:- SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.  Now i can't able to my svg file in my website . I used this animation in my website its not stop to S position.

Comment: Yes, SMIL animations are subject to be removed in further browser versions of Chrome at least (and is not supported in IE and Edge) and it is instead recommended to use CSS animations instead (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL).

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher Google have cancelled their deprecation of SMIL.

Comment: @SayaSharma the deprecation has been cancelled, I assum this message will disappear in future versions of Chrome.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, I didn't know that - do you have a source?

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146086/without-smil-is-gif-my-only-option/39180253#39180253