# Creating interactive SVG maps for a web portal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, maps

I'm creating a web portal with maps in SVG format and set in the HTML code using `<object>` tag in order to preserve the possibility of interactivity. My main problem is how to create and support an interactive SVG format in the browser?

As far as I have researched there are several options:

1. SMIL animation directly in SVG,
2. CSS animation,
3. JavaScript libraries.

It seems to me that this last option has the most potential. There are many libraries (Snap.svg, svg.js, Velocity.js, d3.js, jVectorMap.js, GreenSock ....) to use, so I would appreciate if someone could give some tips on which of them to use.

Do I need to use them within the SVG directly using the `<script>` tag or using an external .js file? To my knowledge, jQuery can't be used directly within SVG.

Comment: On each even we need to redraw the SVG.

Comment: It's going to depend on what exactly you mean by "interactivity".

Comment: Effects such as increasing the size of the symbols on the map by mouse hover,  enlargement of an area or line element (country or river) on a mouse click, multiple layers with the ability to display and hide them, get additional information through pop-up menu by clicking on a specific element of the map, panning and zooming of the map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, all three variants work more or less with different advantages and drawbacks.

**1. SMIL**

SMIL is easy to use inside of your SVG and allows modifying attributes of your SVG object directly. However, if you want/need to support Internet Explorer or Edge, you don't have much luck (see [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=smil)).

Chrome 45 deprecated SMIL in favor of CSS animations and Web animations. But the Chrome developers recently suspended their intent (see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146086/without-smil-is-gif-my-only-option/39180253#39180253))).

**2. CSS Animations**

These are a good alternative for animation of SVGs. The implementation is normally very fast and smooth, as far as I saw it. [Browser support is better](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) especially with Microsoft Browsers. So I would really recommend it.

If you need some more user interaction, you get to the limits of CSS animations quickly. Some interaction is possible, but if you want more, you need JavaScript.

**3. JavaScript libraries**

jQuery really have serious problems with SVGs, but I think it is better doing without jQuery (for both, jQuery and your software) because if it would support SVGs, it would be even larger and slower. However, if you already *have* jQuery included, it is possible to select elements and then animate them without jQuery.

Other libraries are more specialized for SVG and work really great (I myself worked with d3.js with good results).

**Recommendation**

If you don't need to support Microsoft browsers, then SMIL can be an easy and compact way to define certain animations.

If you need those browsers, I would recommend trying CSS animations. But if that seems too static, one of the JavaScript libraries may help.

Comment: Thanks! I worked mostly with SMIL animation, but I came across their intention to cease to supporting it. It makes me a little discouraged. The good news is that for now they abandoned the idea.

CSS animation I started to study more detailed, but somehow it seems limited to what we do. Perhaps the best solution is to immediately start to study some of the JS libraries that support SVG for some more complex things.

Personally, I am most concerned about the speed performance of the animation, because I do everything locally on computer, and the main goal is to publish it on the Internet.

Comment: The good thing is, that JavaScript runs locally on the computer of every visitor. The less good is, that this might mean very old, very slow computers... Depends on your users. ;-)

Comment: Users are primarily school and students. I set a complicated question that really builds on this. The project is the same. [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958781/interactive-map-with-multiple-layers-of-svg-within-html)